# is && in short circuit logic the same as in if clauses?

Tags: javascript

Does the logical and operator (&&) or the logical or operator (||) have the same function in an 'if clause' as in it does in short circuit logic?

For example, && in short circuit should return the first falsey value, otherwise the last value if none is found: eg `0 && 1` returns 1. But if thats the case, how can it work in an if clause?

`if (false && 1)`

wont run because both conditions aren't true, yet short circuit seems to dictate that it will return 1, in which case 1 is a truthy value and the if clause should pass?

Edit: My mistake, I mixed up && and || in short circuit. They work the same as conditionals

Comment: "eg `0 && 1` returns 1." No it doesn't. It returns `0` in both short-circuit and if-statement logic.

Comment: `0 && 1` returns—ah, beaten to it by a few seconds.

Comment: Expressions work how they work regardless of the context.

Comment: Also you can go to your browser console and type `console.log(0 && 1)` and see what it says.

Answer (score 2):

> `&&` in short circuit should return the first falsey value, otherwise the last value if none is found

Correct.

> eg `0 && 1` returns `1`

Nope. `0 && 1` returns the first falsey value, which is `0`.

> `if (false && 1)` wont run because both conditions aren't true

Correct. `false && 1` returns the first falsey value, which is `false`. Since `false` is falsey, the if-statement doesn't run.

> yet short circuit seems to dictate that it will return 1, in which case 1 is a truthy value and the if clause should pass?

Nope. As you said, it returns the first falsey value, which is `false`. The value of any of the later terms doesn't matter: `if(false && something_that_crashes_the_browser())` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Short circuit logic works the same as if-statement logic — there's really no difference, they're just conditionals:

```js
console.log(0 && 1);
if (0 && 1) console.log("0 && 1");
console.log(false && 1);
if (false && 1) console.log("false && 1");
```